# Using LIKE in MySQL SELECT fields

Tags: sql, mysql

I've been trying to select the status of doing a `LIKE` comparison:

```
SELECT (`my_column` LIKE '%thepattern'%) AS `did_match`
```

Thanks!

Edit: Just to clarify this was used so I could get this:

```
SELECT
     (CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%keyword%' THEN 20 ELSE 0 END) +
     (CASE WHEN `desc` LIKE '%keyword%' THEN 10 ELSE 0 END)
     AS `match`
FROM myTable
ORDER BY `match`
```

Comment: typo? should be '%thepattern%'

Comment: Yeah, %keyword% and %thepattern% are the same in my example. Came back and posted the edit later on, using different working sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, and it looks like OMG Ponies has figured it out better than I have, but in case this helps:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN `my_column` LIKE '%thepattern%' 
       THEN 'did_match' ELSE 'no_match' END CASE AS MYTEST
  FROM ...
```

[Link to CASE statement documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html).

Comment: Adam: I'm not 100% that I understand what the OP intended.  Hopefully they'll clarify

Comment: Thanks guys, two potential solutions is better than one!

Comment: Just wanted to add that this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
SELECT t.my_column AS did_match
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
 WHERE t.my_column LIKE '%thepattern%'
```

Replace `YOUR_TABLE` with the name of your table...

Without a `FROM` clause, MySQL (and SQL Server) will allow the query, but not against any data.

Comment: This will work if he only wants columns that do match. You are right on the from <table>.